# Pointing multiple domains to same hosting account

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, domain

I have an application running on a server. I want to point multiple (10+) domains to this application.

My hosting company is different than my domain registrar. Once the domain is registered, I change the DNS to point to my hosting server.. is that enough to route things properly?

Answer (score 1):

The Web server will display the default site for the IP.  If the site displayed by IP is what you want all the domains to point to, yes.

Otherwise, you will need to configure virtual hosts to accommodate your desired configuration.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, this won't be enough.  You'll end up getting the "default" domain for each of your other domain names.  By default, I mean the host's default site.  (try browsing directly to the IP only of that host...)  Most hosting companies setup "virtualhosts" for each customer instead of a unique server & ip per-customer.  You will probably need to contact them and they can setup the "alias" domains for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you talk about a web app.

If you configure the webserver at your hosting company to accept queries for all domains in question, the "routing" part should be OK. That doesn't necessarily mean that things would work when your application is not prepared to properly handle queries from different domains.